# Is Ifrit alive?

Tags: reincarnated-as-a-slime

In [Episode 7](https://youtu.be/n1KBzzkoBTs?t=1227), Rimuru Tempest used **Predator** skill to devour him. After that, he was summoned by Veldora inside the Unlimited Imprisonment ([Episode 24.5](https://youtu.be/opibs265fJ0?t=117)).

Is he alive? If yes, can he get out with Veldora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Ifrit is alive and can be let out by Rimuru. This becomes evident in season 2.